# What does "not be in or not be well" mean?

Tags: meaning

Margaret speaks to Armand about painter Vincent:

> Margaret: Father told me I was distracting Vincent from important work.
> Asked if I really wanted to be responsible for preventing masterpieces
> from being born? And, of course I didn‘t. So I started to **not be in or not be well**
> when Vincent called.

What does "not be in or not be well" mean?

Comment: She avoided meeting Vincent by getting her family to say she was ***out / not in*** (away from home) or ***sick / unwell*** (and in bed / unable to receive visitors) whenever Vincent came a-courting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase indicates that whenever Vincent called, he was given an excuse why she could not see him.  She intentionally avoided seeing Vincent.

"not be in" = When Vincent asked for her, he was told that she was "not in".

"not be well" = When Vincent asker for her, he was told that she was "not well".